# Render caption in Swiper Slider outside of Slide

Tags: javascript, pagination, swiper.js, caption

I'm using the swiper.js slider (https://swiperjs.com) and would like to add captions to the slides via data-attributes and render them in a fixed div outside my slides (i'm using the cube effect and don't want them to move):

```
<div class="swiper-container"> 
    <div class="swiper-caption"></div>
    <div class="swiper-wrapper"> 
        <div class="swiper-slide" data-caption="caption-1"></div>
        <div class="swiper-slide" data-caption="caption-2"></div>
        <div class="swiper-slide" data-caption="caption-3"></div>
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

in js, I'm grabbing the the active slide and its caption:

```
var activeSlide = document.querySelector('div.swiper-slide-active');
var caption = activeSlide.dataset.caption;
```

and try to render it in my captions div:

```
var updateCaptions = function () {
    if (activeSlide.hasAttribute('data-caption')) {
        captions.innerHTML = caption
    };
}
updateCaptions()
```

But the script returns me just the caption of the first (initial) slide. When I slide through the slideshow, the caption doesn't get replaced with the new (active) caption.

How can I make the function run again each time I have a new active slide?

Comment: How did you render the text itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you could **catch en [event](https://swiperjs.com/api/#events)** like `slideChange` to run your function `updateCaptions` each time there is a new active slide. Something like :

```
var mySwiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container');
mySwiper.on('slideChange', function () {
  updateCaptions();
});
```

Comment: @mollini: I hope this will be helpful, if not it would be helpful if you could provide a code snippet to help debugging .

Comment: It worked, but I had to run the function twice. One for the event ('slideChangeTransitionEnd', otherwise it would just render the caption of the previous slide), and another for the initial slide.